# Return the latest count of emitted values from Observable during subscription

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I am looking for a way to have a running counter of emitted values and use that number as well as the "real" values emitted by the `Observable`.

### Marble

```
Obs: |--  A  ---  B  -----  C  ----  D  |
Res: |--[A,1]---[B,2]-----[C,3]----[D,4]|
```

So, I want the new Observable to emit an array that has both the count as well as the original value in it.

### Code

```
var letters = Rx.Observable.of(A, B, C, D);
var result = letters.thisOperator(); //version 1
var result = Rx.Observable.thisOperator(letters); // 2
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
[A, 1]
[B, 2]
[C, 3]
[D, 4]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` for this:

```
Rx.Observable.of('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')
  .map((val, i) => [val, i])
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Or you can make the `map` even easier:

```
.map((...args) => args)
```

This prints:

```
[ 'A', 0 ]
[ 'B', 1 ]
[ 'C', 2 ]
[ 'D', 3 ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am an idiot. I was looking and looking for a way all the while not thinking about the obvious.